# Measuring the frequency of a 0-5V signal with DMM and no oscilloscope?

Tags: frequency, multimeter

I'm trying to determine whether I can use a DMM to monitor a 0-5V signal of a cam and crank sensor.  Both are magnetic.  I have a 5V ref. The sensors should vary between 0V and 5V with a short pause at 5V. I have an image of the correct waveform from a lab scope, but lack the funds to purchase one to test proper.  My DMM measures from 200Hz to 20kHz.

Comment: Does the signal's expected frequency fall within the range your DMM will measure?

Comment: What exactly happened when you set your DMM to Hz and connected the test leads to the signal output? Can you provide a link (URL) to the waveform image you mention?

Comment: what about using a pc with a sound card and free wave analysis software?

Comment: Do you have access to some microcontroller board with an ADC? That and a bit of code would give you a workable waveform data set which you can examine on a PC.

Comment: I'm very curious about the pc/sound card/software idea.  I'll search for a viable image online that's not password protected to link to.  Also, what is an ADC?  The tech I usually work on are $40k computers with 4 wheels and a steering wheel, all are gas powered, lol!

Comment: I didn't find an image url, but I did find a video on youtube. [Chrysler Crank Sensor waveform](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=u5tBWHC-LNs) @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: There are several websites that walk you through testing those sensors with a DMM.  [Example 1](http://troubleshootmyvehicle.com/chrysler/2.7L-3.3L-3.5L-3.8L/how-to-test-the-crankshaft-position-sensor-1), [Example 2](http://easyautodiagnostics.com/crankshaft_position_sensors/crank_cam_sensors_1.php). See also http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Both of those sites are more geared towards checking voltage only.  I'll just test it when I get back on the car, and we'll see what happens.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Last comment just as a "fix".  The signal from the crank is way to fast to see with a DMM.  The signal from the cam however is much slower and can be seen by watching the voltage change from around 5V to 0V. Still, a scope is the only option.  Thank you all for your help and input.